# Як правильно інтерпретувати вираз "Хочете щастя? Менше бурчіть, більше мурчіть."

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, синоніми

[image]

СУМ-11

> [Бурчати](http://sum.in.ua/s/burchaty) 1. перех. і без додатка. Говорити невиразно,
> нерозбірливо.  //  Докучливо висловлювати своє невдоволення
> чим-небудь, дорікати комусь.
>
> [Мурчати](http://sum.in.ua/s/murchaty) 1. неперех. Те саме, що муркотати. 2. перех. і без
> додатка, перен., розм. Те саме, що мурмотати
>
> [Муркотати](http://sum.in.ua/s/murkotaty)1. неперех. Безперестанно видавати звуки «мур-мур» (про
> котів та інших котячих). 2. перех. і без додатка, перен., розм. Те
> саме, що мурмотати
>
> [Мурмотати,](http://sum.in.ua/s/murmotaty) мурмотіти очу, отиш, недок., розм. 1. перех. і без
> додатка. Говорити тихо, невиразно.

В [Словнику синонімів Полюги](http://slovopedia.org.ua/31/53393/27502.html) слова "бурмотіти" та "муркотіти" подаються як синоніми

> БУРЧАТИ  (неприязно висловлювати своє незадоволення) буркотіти,
> миркати, мурчати, бубоніти.

Як правильно інтерпретувати вираз з картинки?

Comment: Дякую. Як це ви зробили?

Comment: [як змінити розмір зображення з imgur](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово буркотіти у цьому контексті має таке [значення](http://sum.in.ua/s/burkotaty):

> "Говорити невиразно і сердито, висловлюючи невдоволення ким-,
>   чим-небудь; **бурчати**"

[Бурчати](http://sum.in.ua/s/burchaty):

> "Докучливо висловлювати своє невдоволення чим-небудь, дорікати
>   комусь."

Муркотати тут означає "отримувати задоволення". Навіть на картинці, яку ви прикріпили, зображені кішки. Більшість людей вважає, що вони муркочуть, коли їм добре (хоч це і не зовсім [так](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/features-44957995)). А ще я не раз чув такий вислів: "Муркотіти від задоволення". Мені вдалося знайти деяки приклади вживання цього вислову в книжках:

> Лариса від задоволення мало не муркотіла, як кішка на сонці. затемнені
>   ("[Мудрі жінки](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=alNHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT198&dq=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQtoCh4OXgAhUjqYsKHcyFABAQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&f=false)").

Виходить, що **в цьому випадку** слова "буркотіти" та "муркотати" - антоніми. І вираз можна пояснити як:

"Менше висловлюйте незадоволення, більше отримуйте задоволення".